# Scala: Int to BigDecimal conversion?

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I stumbled upon this problem and wasn't able to find a solution anywhere.

**How can I get a `BigDecimal` from an `Int` in Scala 2.12?**

As far as I am concerned, this conversion is simple and straightforward. Why is it that I am unable to find an implementation of it?

Comment: `BigDecimal(x)` where `x` is an `Int`,

Comment: What do you mean "find an implementation"?

Comment: Well I expected some form of implementation like `Int.toBigDecimal(Int n)` or `BigDecimal.fromInt(Int n)`. The answers of @Sergey Lagutin and @jwvh are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via constructor:

```
BigDecimal(1)
```

Via implicit conversion:

```
val i : BigDecimal = 1 // defined in BigDecimal object
```